# location and size of a frame into different classes

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a UIView class, to create the structure, I do:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code

    //creo la view
    CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100); //I would just like the frame size
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
    }
return self;
}
```

so I make the location and size of the frame.
I call this class in the main UIViewController
is there a way to just create the size of frame in the class, and in the UIViewController set the position?

```
MyClass *myClass1 = [[Item alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)]; //I would just like the frame position
[self.view addSubview:myClass1];
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking at something like `initWithOrigin:`.

```
- (id)initWithOrigin:(CGPoint)origin {
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(100,100);
    CGRect frame;

    frame.origin = origin;
    frame.size = size;

    return [self initWithFrame:frame];
}
```

Now you can use it as,

```
MyClass *myClass1 = [[MyClass alloc] initWithOrigin:CGPointMake(0,0)];
[self.view addSubview:myClass1];
```